# go build *.go в Windows

Tags: windows, golang, cmd

Не компилируется под Windows этой командой:

```
go build *.go
```

Ошибка:

```
go build -o serv project\order\server\*.go
GetFileAttributesEx project\order\server\*.go: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Comment: А что вы ожидали? Windows cmd не знает такой команды. Выполните с консоли git bush.

Comment: у вас командная строка запущена от администратора?))

Comment: не помогает от имени администратора а вот баш гит нормально справился

Comment: переменную среды GOROOT установил?

Comment: А на Windows *.go развернется корректно во все пути с расширениями .go?

Comment: А почему бы и нет, у меня пакет разбит на несколько файлов для удобства)

Comment: Все настроено. Мне уже дали исчерпывающий ответ, данный метод работает в git bush, и не работает в cmd. Предполагаю что он еще работает в shell windows